# Is the inline event listener in JSX bad design?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

Using inline event listeners is considered a bad practice in HTML, but seems inline is the only option to use event listener in React? Is this a bad design?

Comment: "Is this a bad design?" — No. React isn't HTML. JSX isn't HTML.

Comment: No. When you're writing in React-Land you've got to have a completely different mindset from when you're working in vanilla JS and HTML

Comment: But it's not a dumb question to ask, not at all. :-)